# NVL to get around No data Found, how can I handle if it returns no row

Tags: plsql

The rowtype record has no data in its table, and I am trying to use NVL to  put blank data instead of it catching the no data found error. Is there any way around this?
I am trying to add blank data instead of it being null.
how can I handle if it returns no row?

```
PROCEDURE Hi

is

final_qc_data psap20_internal_final_qc%rowtype;

 begin 

--gets the data

 select 
 NVL(ENTITY_ID,''''), NVL(NAME,''''), NVL(ST_CODE,''''),
 NVL(START_DT,''''), NVL(COMPLETE_DT,''''), NVL(P_TIME,''''),
 NVL(NOTES,''''), NVL(JAMES_BOND_ID,'''')
 into final_qc_data 
 from psap20_internal_final_qc
 where entity_id = p_entity_id;

 exception 
     when no_data_found then null;

 end;
```

Comment: What is 'blank data'? In your example the`nvl` expressions return a single quote character (`'`) when there is no value for ENTITY_ID etc. That will only work for strings, though even then I can't see how `'` is 'blank data'.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
PROCEDURE Hi

is

final_qc_data psap20_internal_final_qc%rowtype;

begin 

--gets the data
 begin
 select 
 NVL(ENTITY_ID,''''), NVL(NAME,''''), NVL(ST_CODE,''''),
 NVL(START_DT,''''), NVL(COMPLETE_DT,''''), NVL(P_TIME,''''),
 NVL(NOTES,''''), NVL(JAMES_BOND_ID,'''')
 into final_qc_data 
 from psap20_internal_final_qc
 where entity_id = p_entity_id;

 exception 
     when no_data_found then 

          select '', '', '','', '', '', '', ''
            into final_qc_data 
            from DUAL;


 end;
--continue with program
end;
```